# PostgreSQL failover using poolboy and epgsql

Tags: erlang

I'm building an Erlang application that uses [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy/) for connection pooling, and [epgsql](https://github.com/wg/epgsql) to talk to PostgreSQL.

I'd like to handle PostgreSQL failover, and I'm wondering what the best way to structure my application is.

Should I or can I:

- Have one pool for each PG peer, and handle this above poolboy. That is: when I detect the original PG server is down, can I kill the pool? Is there an Erlang-idiomatic way to decide which pool is still alive?
- Kill and restart the workers when I detect the PG server is down? Is there an idiomatic way to do this?
- Have my workers failover from one PG server to the other?
- Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `epgsql`, when the primary goes down, the socket connection is aborted. Because the connection process is linked to the worker process, the worker process terminates and is restarted by the supervisor.

So, all you have to do is (in `my_worker:init`) handle errors from `pgsql:connect`, and connect to the standby server instead:

```
case pgsql:connect(Primary, Username, Password, Opts) of
    {ok, C} -> {ok, #state{conn=C}};
    _Other -> pgsql:connect(Standby, Username, Password, Opts)
end.
```

In my (admittedly very cursory) testing, this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing to handle redis connection failover(I didn't use poolboy), you can compare it with your case:

```
-record(redis_conn {
 Host,
 Port,
 User,
 Pwd
}).

-record(state{
  redis_connections :: dict()
}).
```

Let's say you start the connections in init function and record the state:

```
State#state{
  redis_connections=Conn
}.
```

Whenever the connection failed, you catch ed the "EXIT" signal, and then do the reconnect.

So you have all your connections in state.